# Change the Location of Page Control

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have page controller which have 4 page the and in the first three the page indicator is at the bottom of the screen and in the last one I want to change it place to be in the top

```
 func newVc(viewController: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }
    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return orderedViewControllers.last
    }
    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }
    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }
    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count
    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return orderedViewControllers.first
    }
    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }
    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
}

func configurePageControl() {
  many available colors we have.
    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

Comment: change the constraint constant when you are at specified index of page control you want your page control to be on top

Comment: but I am creating the PageControl by code

Comment: just update this when you reach at the particular index to move your pagecontrol on top. pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))

Answer (score 0):

Change Your `y position` in page control frame when you reach at a particular index in the page view controller.

Try the following code:

```
pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
```

adjust your Y position in the frame according to your requirement.